# I can get interface but can't get class when using XPCOM to register dll file!

Tags: com, xpcom

I have successful install my dll file to the thunderbird. But in my XPCOMViewer I can only find the interface but not the class so that when I use the component, it shows me the error :
TypeError: Components.classes[cid] is undefined

Here's my all files:

Dear All,

I have successful install my dll file to the thunderbird. But in my XPCOMViewer I can only find the interface but not the class so that when I use the component, it shows me the error :
TypeError: Components.classes[cid] is undefined

Here's my all files:

//IMyComponent.idl

```
#include "nsISupports.idl"

[scriptable, uuid(4782615C-5ACD-11E0-AE9B-68F4DFD72085)]
interface IMyComponent : nsISupports
{
  long Add(in long a, in long b);
};



//IMyComponent.h


/*
 * DO NOT EDIT.  THIS FILE IS GENERATED FROM IMyComponent.idl
 */

#ifndef __gen_IMyComponent_h__
#define __gen_IMyComponent_h__


#ifndef __gen_nsISupports_h__
#include "nsISupports.h"
#endif

/* For IDL files that don't want to include root IDL files. */
#ifndef NS_NO_VTABLE
#define NS_NO_VTABLE
#endif

/* starting interface:    IMyComponent */
#define IMYCOMPONENT_IID_STR "4782615c-5acd-11e0-ae9b-68f4dfd72085"

#define IMYCOMPONENT_IID \
  {0x4782615c, 0x5acd, 0x11e0, \
    { 0xae, 0x9b, 0x68, 0xf4, 0xdf, 0xd7, 0x20, 0x85 }}

class NS_NO_VTABLE NS_SCRIPTABLE IMyComponent : public nsISupports {
 public: 

  NS_DECLARE_STATIC_IID_ACCESSOR(IMYCOMPONENT_IID)

  /* long Add (in long a, in long b); */
  NS_SCRIPTABLE NS_IMETHOD Add(PRInt32 a, PRInt32 b, PRInt32 *_retval NS_OUTPARAM) = 0;

};

  NS_DEFINE_STATIC_IID_ACCESSOR(IMyComponent, IMYCOMPONENT_IID)

/* Use this macro when declaring classes that implement this interface. */
#define NS_DECL_IMYCOMPONENT \
  NS_SCRIPTABLE NS_IMETHOD Add(PRInt32 a, PRInt32 b, PRInt32 *_retval NS_OUTPARAM); 

/* Use this macro to declare functions that forward the behavior of this interface to another object. */
#define NS_FORWARD_IMYCOMPONENT(_to) \
  NS_SCRIPTABLE NS_IMETHOD Add(PRInt32 a, PRInt32 b, PRInt32 *_retval NS_OUTPARAM) { return _to Add(a, b, _retval); } 

/* Use this macro to declare functions that forward the behavior of this interface to another object in a safe way. */
#define NS_FORWARD_SAFE_IMYCOMPONENT(_to) \
  NS_SCRIPTABLE NS_IMETHOD Add(PRInt32 a, PRInt32 b, PRInt32 *_retval NS_OUTPARAM) { return !_to ? NS_ERROR_NULL_POINTER : _to->Add(a, b, _retval); } 

#if 0
/* Use the code below as a template for the implementation class for this interface. */

/* Header file */
class _MYCLASS_ : public IMyComponent
{
public:
  NS_DECL_ISUPPORTS
  NS_DECL_IMYCOMPONENT

  _MYCLASS_();

private:
  ~_MYCLASS_();

protected:
  /* additional members */
};

/* Implementation file */
NS_IMPL_ISUPPORTS1(_MYCLASS_, IMyComponent)

_MYCLASS_::_MYCLASS_()
{
  /* member initializers and constructor code */
}

_MYCLASS_::~_MYCLASS_()
{
  /* destructor code */
}

/* long Add (in long a, in long b); */
NS_IMETHODIMP _MYCLASS_::Add(PRInt32 a, PRInt32 b, PRInt32 *_retval NS_OUTPARAM)
{
    return NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED;
}

/* End of implementation class template. */
#endif


#endif /* __gen_IMyComponent_h__ */



//MyComponentModule.cpp


#include "nsIGenericFactory.h"
#include "MyComponent.h"

NS_GENERIC_FACTORY_CONSTRUCTOR(MyComponent)

static nsModuleComponentInfo components[] =
{
    {
       MY_COMPONENT_CLASSNAME, 
       MY_COMPONENT_CID,
       MY_COMPONENT_CONTRACTID,
       MyComponentConstructor,
    }
};

NS_IMPL_NSGETMODULE("MyComponentsModule", components) 




//MyComponent.h

#ifndef _MY_COMPONENT_H_
#define _MY_COMPONENT_H_

#include "IMyComponent.h"

#define MY_COMPONENT_CONTRACTID "@mozilla.org/XPCOMSample/MyComponent;1"
#define MY_COMPONENT_CLASSNAME "A Simple XPCOM Sample"
#define MY_COMPONENT_CID {0x4782615c, 0x5acd, 0x11e0, \
    { 0xae, 0x9b, 0x68, 0xf4, 0xdf, 0xd7, 0x20, 0x85 }}

/* Header file */
class MyComponent : public IMyComponent
{
public:
  NS_DECL_ISUPPORTS
  NS_DECL_IMYCOMPONENT

  MyComponent();
  virtual ~MyComponent();
  /* additional members */
};


#endif //_MY_COMPONENT_H_



//MyComponent.cpp


#include "MyComponent.h"

NS_IMPL_ISUPPORTS1(MyComponent, IMyComponent)

MyComponent::MyComponent()
{
  /* member initializers and constructor code */
}

MyComponent::~MyComponent()
{
  /* destructor code */
}

/* long Add (in long a, in long b); */
NS_IMETHODIMP MyComponent::Add(PRInt32 a, PRInt32 b, PRInt32 *_retval)
{
    *_retval = a + b;
    return NS_OK;
}




My makefile:

CC=cl.exe
CCPARMS=/D "XP_WIN" /D "XP_WIN32"


all: MyComponent.obj MyComponentModule.obj link

MyComponent.obj:
    $(CC) $(CCPARMS) /c MyComponent.cpp

MyComponentModule.obj:
    $(CC) $(CCPARMS) /c MyComponentModule.cpp

link:
    link.exe /DLL /out:"MyComponent.dll" /implib:"MyComponent.lib" /machine:I386 xpcom.lib xpcomglue_s.lib nspr4.lib "MyComponent.obj" "MyComponentModule.obj"


clean:
    del *.lib *.dll *.obj *.exp
```

Comment: What do you mean by "install"?

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: Components.classes[cid] is undefined

This suggests that your component is not installed properly.

Here are the Steps to install a new *XPCOM component* in FF 3.6

- Copy the .dll and .xpt file to <%ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox\components> directory
- In the %ProgramFiles%\Mozilla Firefox\components directory, there is a file named “componets.list”. Just simply add name of your dll file, this will force the registration
- Now delete compreg.dat and  xpti.dat files from your profile directory before staring firefox.exe.

Start Firefox now and your component must be registered automatically.

Comment: This is the manual way of doing it, it would be better to package the extension in an xpi file and distribute it, as not everyone wants to fiddle with the files like that.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your install.rdf, under the description section:

```
<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>
```

e.g.:

```
<Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>blah@blah.com</em:id>
    <em:version>1.0</em:version>
    <em:type>2</em:type>
    <em:unpack>true</em:unpack>
    ...
```

This is because XPCOM binaries require to be unpacked to be usable see doc:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Install_Manifests

Under unpack.